# UWP Apps and the start menu

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've googled pretty much but i can't seem to find any information on this..

I've cloned a [project](https://github.com/UnigramDev/Unigram) from github, it opens and builds no problem. it's also added to my start menu.
I can run the program from my start menu as if it was a "normal" program.

Now I have made some changes to the sources and built it, and the changes seem to be present in the installed version (which I start from start menu) just by themselves.

my question is: is that really the case? do UWP apps get installed and updated automatically? is there a way to NOT update my installed version with my release-build every time? it seems wrong, did I miss something? (did I maybe "install" the changes somewhere along the way without noticing/by double-clicking the executable etc.) and: can I replace the executable that is started in the start menu? I tried to find where it is stored/linked, but I couldn't find anything, as there is zero information in the start menu.

Or can I rely on the start menu version always being my latest release build?
I'm confused, if someone has any information on this, I'd be really happy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct whenever you build and run the app on the local machine using Visual Studio it gets deployed to the system apps from where you can run it. So each time you build and run with any changes they will be updated in the system installed app as well(Basically they are same)

If you want that these changes do not get reflected in the system's app then I think you can use Device emulators available in the Visual Studio.

Comment: You can also (temporarily) change the identity of the app in the appx manifest if you want.